# Improve loading speed of dynamic contents over the world

Tags: mysql, dynamic, country

I've a website that redistributes dynamic contents.
It takes the data from a database and then it generates dynamic images with them.
Data being updated about every 3 minutes.
My server is located in EU, and now i'm wondering if is better off buy another server located in USA to improve the images loading time.

At the moment i'm using MySQL on a linux based os.
I was thinking to replicate all php pages on the secondary server and connect it to the main server who store my database. Is it convenient?

Comment: Depending on how much data resides in your database & how much data is in the end results, the results may be everywhere between considerable to even worse performance due to the remote DB connection. A caching CDN could help if you really want to work globally and the images are cachable, a remote db kept in sync with replication could work if you are only interested in 1 other locality.

Comment: is not my case:  data being refreshed every 3 minutes, so i can't cache it... anyway what you mean with "remote db kept in sync"? If i copy the database on secondary server, on each refresh i should update the second db, and so waste tons of bandwidth

Comment: Depending on your traffic, being able the cache for 3 minutes could be a _huge_ improvement. Keeping replicated database in sync would require some bandwidth, but in most use cases far less then querying every single query across the pond (i.e. data selected by clients > alterations done on database). (Your case _may_ differ). I you mean to copy over the entire db again & again, that is not what I meant, look at [MySQL's replication features](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication.html)